PowerBI Power Query "We cannot apply field access to the type Binary"
I need a hand trying to find why I am receiving "We cannot apply field access to the type Binary
"
This is the function that I've defined, I've removed the token and the directory name for security purposes:
let gettoken=() =>
    let
    JWT="<my_token>",
    Data= Web.Contents("https://api.github.com/app/installations/<id>/access_tokens", 
                      [
                        Headers=[
                                    #"Accept"="application/vnd.github+json",
                                    #"Authorization"="Bearer" & JWT,
                                    #"X-GitHub-Api-Version"="2022-11-28",
                                    #"Content-Type"="application/x-www-form-urlencoded"                                 
                        ]])
        ,token=Text.FromBinary(Json.Document(Data[token]))
in
    token   
in gettoken

No syntax errors, but when I run it...
An error occurred in the ‘get_token’ query. Expression.Error: We cannot apply field access to the type Binary.
Details:
    Value=[Binary]
    Key=token

Any help would be really appreciated.

Try taking out the # in the headers. Ive never seen code for headers that use #
